# parsing error in angularjs with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following snippet and it gave me parsing error.

```
<a class="pointer" role="menuitem" ng-repeat="rec in cfg.popupAssoc" ng-click="followSession(\"{{$index}}\")" tabindex="{{$index + 2}}"
    {{rec.popupEntry}}
</a>
```

after I changed `\"{{$index}}\"` to `this`, it doesn't have the compile error.

Any idea why? Thanks.

**UPDATE1**

The basic problem is, I want to pass something (could be a string with white space) to a function, but can't figure a way to do it.  The following code is a naive attempt but it gives angular parsing error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr >
    <td ng-click="dum();">ONE</td>
    <td>TWO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td ng-click="dum({{x.Name}});" myid="{{$index + 1}}">{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
obj1 = "haha";
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
    $scope.dum = function(x) { obj1 = x; console.log(x); }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Not necessarily the cause of the error, but you can just use single quotes instead of escaping your double quotes

Comment: Why does the "full" code not contain the snippet? What do those two pieces of code have to do with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use {{}} inside an ng-click. That is the cause of the parse error. Just remove them and it should work. The ng-repeat makes x available on scope. You don't have to wrap it in {{}} in this case.

Comment: Thanks @lwalden. Thanks for pointing out my problem with `{{}}`!

Answer (score 2):

You need to update from

```
<a class="pointer" role="menuitem" ng-repeat="rec in cfg.popupAssoc" ng-click="followSession(\"{{$index}}\")" tabindex="{{$index + 2}}"
    {{rec.popupEntry}}
</a>
```

to

```
<a class="pointer" role="menuitem" ng-repeat="rec in cfg.popupAssoc" ng-click="followSession($index)" tabindex="{{$index + 2}}"
    {{rec.popupEntry}}
</a>
```

Comment: @PankajParkar - Yes I did. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What if I need the double quote for the function, in another words, I want to the function call to be like `followSession("12")`?  Thanks.

Comment: You can update `ng-click="followSession($index)"` to `ng-click="followSession($index+'')"`

Comment: Thanks @nikhil. My root problem is, I want to pass a string (with spaces) to function `followSession`.

Comment: I think such kind of manipulations should be done in your function.

Comment: @nikhil, updated the question earlier. Wonder if the new question (in update) makes it clear the problem I am faced with? Thanks.